# SQL: Update All Selected Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

In the following code.  Only one of the 'Select' statements will be executed at a time. I want to be able to update the 'Status' of any of the selected rows as well as return the data.  This basically prevents fetching of the same records during backend processing.

Thanks!

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
if(@BatchSize > -1 and @Priority > -1)
begin
    Select TOP(@BatchSize) *,ID 
    From CompingQueue 
    Where PriorityLevel=@Priority 
       and Status=35 
    order by PriorityLevel asc;
end
if(@BatchSize = -1 and @Priority = -1)
begin
    Select * From CompingQueue 
    Where Status=35 
    order by PriorityLevel asc;
end

if(@BatchSize = -1 and @Priority > -1)
begin
   Select * From CompingQueue 
   WHEre PriorityLevel=@Priority 
     and Status=35     
   order by PriorityLevel asc;
end
if(@BatchSize > -1 and @Priority = -1)
begin
    Select TOP(@BatchSize) * 
    From CompingQueue 
    Where Status=35 
    order by PriorityLevel asc;
end
--update CompingQueue set Status = 2 where ID=
-- Set the Status Flag for each job
```

END

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DECLARE @tblResults TABLE (...). Insert the SELECT'ed rows into the table variable. The perform a join from the source table to the table variable on the PK, using this join as the clause in an UPDATE statement, then return the variable as the query/proc/func result.

Comment: You don't even need to store all the rows in @tblResults you could just store the primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just `UPDATE` the table and use [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to store the updated rows in a table variable. You can then `SELECT` or process the data in the table variable further.

There is an example in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You want the `OUTPUT` clause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Sounds like you want something like

```
UPDATE c
SET somestuff = something
OUTPUT DELETED.*
FROM CompingQueue c
WHERE someotherstuff
```

Or, if you want the post-update data, use `INSERTED.*` instead of `DELETED.*`.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing them all at once like this:

```
Declare @NumRecs int
if @BatchSize > -1 Set @NumRecs = @BatchSize 
else Select @NumRecs = Count(*) From CompingQueue 
-- --------------------------
Declare @Ids table (id int primary key not null)
Insert @Ids(id)
Select top(@numRecs) id 
From CompingQueue 
Where Status=35 
   And PriorityLevel = Case 
      When @Priority > -1 Then @Priority 
      Else PriorityLevel End
Order by PriorityLevel asc;

 Select * From CompingQueue 
 Where Id In (Select id from @Ids);

 Update CompingQueue Set
    status = 2
 Where Id In (Select id from @Ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL CTE will hel you for your case. You are trying to avoid concurreny issue, because multiple processes may get same records to update. And in your query, you have the top batch, so directly update...output maybe not the best choice. **CTE + xlock,rowlock** will be better choice

```
;with Update_batch 
as 
(
  select top 10 * from compingqueue With (xlock, rowlock)
  order by PriorityLevel desc
)
update Update_batch
set ....=....
```

You can treat CTE as on-fly view, with **(xlock, rowlock)**, when rows are selected, an **(xlock, rowlock)** will be put on the row, which will make sure other processes could not even get the same rows.